# Syntax highlighting strongly varying from one color scheme to another

Tags: sublimetext2

I currently have lots of documentation to write in markdown and, therefore, I'd like my favorite editor to properly syntax-highlight it.

Problem is: the default color scheme of SublimeText (in my case, *Monokai*) doesn't seem to make a good use of colors with markdown.  [See by yourself](http://uppix.net/kqZWJW.png).

That being, while searching for a solution, I found [a comment on github](https://gist.github.com/CrazyApi/2354062#comment-845348) mentioning other color schemes working way better for markdown: [Cobalt](http://uppix.net/2c2GCj.png), [Dawn](http://uppix.net/7wDj5m.png) and [Sunburst](http://uppix.net/I7Ggrm.png).

The thing is I'm pretty used to Monokai (never switched to another color scheme so far) and I'd like to avoid switching everytime I have to work with markdown.

1. Why does syntax highlight vary that much while I'm only using non-exotic themes ?
2. More important: what can I do ?

Comment: Note that I'm using Ubuntu, so if there are any specific solutions related to this OS, I'm also interested.

Comment: I've made the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) that may work for you. I've tried to make it as consistent as possible between languages, and if you'd like me to make any changes I'm definitely [open to suggestions](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-sublime-theme/issues/new). Please let me know what you think, it's still pretty new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's slightly annoying, but you can customize the existing color scheme. You simply need to determine the scopes for certain blocks of code, then create a color "binding" for that. I'd recommend copying the contents of the Monokai color scheme out and saving it in `Packages/User`. That way, you aren't messing up the built in one if you accidentally mess things up beyond repair. This also makes it easy to move the color scheme between machines (if that applies to you).

To determine scope, I'd recommend using [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter). There is built in functionality also, but I like ScopeHunter better (but that's a personal preference). To find the default key bindings, search for the command "show_scope_name`. You can look at the entries already there for an example of how to set up colors, though if you need some additional clarification, please comment as such. Oh and if you would rather work in JSON instead of XML, you might also want to take a look at [PlistJsonConverter](https://github.com/facelessuser/PlistJsonConverter)

As an alternative, you can try to find someone who has already made the appropriate modifications to the color scheme file.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up !  But the thing I don't understand is more: why does Sublime perfectly handles MD with some color schemes while it doesn't with some others ?

Comment: @Anto - It all depends on the scopes the color scheme is built to handle. Some have only a few generalized ones, others are very specific. You can get a general idea by just looking at the size of the `.tmTheme` file - Monokai is ~9KB, while my [Neon](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) theme is 34KB. Monokai just has one color for `variable`, while Neon has about 15 different variable classes. Markdown also has some specialized scopes (`markup.bold`, `markup.heading`) that don't exist in other languages, and may not be handled by some themes.

Comment: @MattDMo Ok, now I understand it better.  Thanks a lot !  Tried Neon, pretty sweet ;)